# php newbie question: classes

Tags: php, class

i'm new to php and am wondering - is it possible to initialize a class with parameters?
like `$obj = new myClass('myID');`

i've tried but it gave me an error.

maybe someone can point me to some good tutorials.

thanks

Comment: We need the code for your class.

Comment: +1 for the code, and also for the specific error message you are getting.
With regard to tutorials, a Google Search on "PHP Intorduction to Classes", "introduction to OOP PHP" and "PHP object oriented tutorial" yields a bevy of tutorials from which to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, you need to pass the variables through the constructor:

```
class SomeClass
{
    function __construct($some_var)
    {
    }
}
```

Please note that in older versions of php the constructor needs to have the name of the class, it´s `__construct()` since php 5.

Comment: The name of the class in PHP4 (`function SomeClass($someVar)`), and as you have stated for PHP5. Older PHP4 code will work in PHP5 if __construct is not found on the class definition.

Comment: Just for completeness -- as of PHP 5.3.3, using the name of the class as a constructor won't work in certain namespaced situations, so it's best not to do that at all (esp. for forward compatibility). See [this manual page](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to use a class constructor.

**Example:**

```
<?php

class ClassWithArgs
{
  function __construct($argument1, $argument2)
  {
    echo "arg 1 = $argument1\n";
    echo "arg 2 = $argument2\n";
  }
}

$object = new ClassWithArgs('one', 'two');

?>
```

**Example Output**

```
arg 1 = one
arg 2 = two
```

I suggest you also take a look at the PHP5 OOP documentation, it includes simple examples to get you going: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php